# How do you sort pointers, not whole structs in C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, struct, qsort

I am new to c and I am attempting to sort pointers and not structs. However, the code I am providing is not working. I have spent over 6 hours trying to work it out but I have gotten nowhere. The issue seems to be comparing strings pointed to by pointers. The code using pointers is failing the auto checker, including everything else. Although, when I submit the code not using pointers everything passes except for sort pointers, not whole structs.

My attempt at using pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct strdef {                          /*strdef = structure definition*/

        float sheet;                     /*32-bit floating point*/
        uint32_t condition;              /*32-bit boolean*/
        uint64_t ant;                    /*64-bit unsigned integer*//*hexadecimal converted to  decimal number 457*/
        uint32_t crack;                  /*32-bit integer*//*decimal value 47 converted to octal notation*/
        uint32_t throne;                 /*32-bit integer*/
        bool trade;                      /*8-bit boolean*/
        bool cry;                        /*8-bit boolean*/
        uint32_t pigs;                   /*32-bit boolean*/
        uint32_t quartz;                 /*32-bit boolean*/
        char wash[9];                    /*at most 9-bit string*/
        char industry;                   /*8-bit character*/
        double pin;                      /*64-bit floating point*/
        float doctor;                    /*32-bit floating point*/
        int16_t plantation;              /*16-bit integer*//*Convert from decimal to hexadecimal*/
        uint8_t scarf;                   /*8-bit integer*//*decimal value 125 converted to octal notation*/
        int8_t lake;                     /*8-bit integer*/
        bool jump;                       /*8-bit boolean*/

};

    int max_ele=1;
int MAX=37;

//THE COMPARATOR FUNCTION.
int comp(const void * aa, const void * bb)
{   struct strdef *left = *(struct strdef**)aa;
    struct strdef *right = *(struct strdef**)bb;
    printf("sheet checked %f  %f  \n\n",&(left->sheet),&(right->sheet));
    if (&left->sheet==&right->sheet)
    {   if ((struct strdef *)&left->ant==(struct strdef *)&right->ant)  
        {   if (&left->pigs==&right->pigs)  
            {   if (&left->industry==&right->industry)  
        {   if (&left->pin==&right->pin)    
            {   if (&left->quartz==&right->quartz)  
            {   if (&left->condition==&right->condition)    
                {   if (&left->jump==&right->jump)  
                {   if (&left->doctor==&right->doctor)  
                    {   if (&left->throne==&right->throne)  
                    {   if (&left->crack==&right->crack)
                        {   if (&left->plantation==&right->plantation)  
                        {   printf("will now check wash\n\n");
                            printf("\n%p\t%c\n\n",&left->wash,&right->wash);
//This right here is the problem
                        if (strcmp(&left->wash,&right->wash)==0)    
                            {   if (&left->cry==&right->cry)    
                            {   if (&left->lake==&right->lake)  
                                {   if (&left->scarf==&right->scarf)        
                                {   if (&left->trade==&right->trade)    
                                        return 0;
                                    else if (&left->trade < &right->trade)  //trade -- desc
                                    return 1;
                                    else
                                    return -1;
                                }
                                else if (&left->scarf < &right->scarf)  //scarf -- desc
                                    return 1;
                                else
                                    return -1;
                                }
                                else if (&left->lake < &right->lake)        //lake -- desc
                                return 1;
                                else
                                return -1;
                            }
                            else if (&left->cry < &right->cry)          //cry -- asc
                                return -1;
                            else
                                return 1;
                            }
                            else if (strcmp(left->wash,right->wash)>0)      //wash -- asc
                            return 1;
                            else
                            return -1;
                        }
                        else if (&left->plantation < &right->plantation)        //plantation -- asc
                            return -1;
                        else
                            return 1;
                        }
                        else if (&left->crack < &right->crack)              //crack -- asc
                        return -1;
                        else
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else if (&left->throne < &right->throne)                //throne -- desc
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return -1;
                    }
                    else if (&left->doctor < &right->doctor)                //doctor -- asc
                    return -1;
                    else
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (&left->jump < &right->jump)                    //jump -- asc
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 1;
                }                   
                else if (&left->condition < &right->condition)                  //condition -- desc
                return 1;
                else
                return -1;
            }
            else if (&left->quartz < &right->quartz)                        //quartz -- asc
                return -1;
            else
                return 1;
            }
            else if (&left->pin < &right->pin)                          //pin -- desc
            return 1;
            else
            return -1;
        }
        else if (&left->industry < &right->industry)                        //industry -- desc
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
            }
            else if (&left->pigs < &right->pigs)                                //pigs -- asc
            return -1;
            else
            return 1;
        }
        else if (&left->ant < &right->ant)                                  //ant -- desc
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    else if (&left->sheet < &right->sheet)                                  //sheet -- desc
            return 1;
    else
            return -1;
} // comp

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Declaring File pointer
    FILE *f;
    //opening File in read-binary mode
    f=fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    //Defining Struct strdef variable
    struct strdef rec1;
    //Checking if File is found and opened.
    if (f == NULL)
    {   fprintf(stderr, "%s File Not found\n",argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!f)
    {   printf( "Usage: %s inputfile %s outputfile\n", argv[1],argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //DYNAMICALL ALLOCATE MEMORY BLOCK.
    struct strdef * arr = (struct strdef*)malloc(sizeof(struct strdef)*MAX);
    struct strdef * arr_nw=NULL;
    int i=0;

    //Read file until End Of File is reached.
    while(1) 
    {   fread(&rec1.sheet,sizeof(rec1.sheet),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.condition,sizeof(rec1.condition),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.ant,sizeof(rec1.ant),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.crack,sizeof(rec1.crack),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.throne,sizeof(rec1.throne),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.trade,sizeof(rec1.trade),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.cry,sizeof(rec1.cry),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.pigs,sizeof(rec1.pigs),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.quartz,sizeof(rec1.quartz),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.wash,sizeof(rec1.wash),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.industry,sizeof(rec1.industry),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.pin,sizeof(rec1.pin),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.doctor,sizeof(rec1.doctor),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.plantation,sizeof(rec1.plantation),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.scarf,sizeof(rec1.scarf),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.lake,sizeof(rec1.lake),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.jump,sizeof(rec1.jump),1,f);
        
        //When end of file reached, Break loop.
        if(feof(f)!=0)
                break;      
            
            //CHECK WHEN ALLOCATED MEMORY BLOCK IS OVER
            if(i>=MAX)
        {   arr_nw = realloc(arr,sizeof(struct strdef)*(i+1));
            
            if(arr_nw==NULL)
            {   printf("reallocation not done");
                break;
            }
            else
            {   arr_nw[i]=rec1;
                arr=arr_nw;
            }
        }
            
        else
                *(arr+i)=rec1;
            i++;    

    }
    //CLOSE FILE POINTER
    fclose(f);
     

    max_ele=i;      //SET NUMBER OF RECORDS.
//QSORT FUNCTION CALL
    qsort(arr,max_ele,sizeof(struct strdef),comp);
//FILE POINTER FOR WRITE OPERATION
    FILE * outf;
        outf=fopen(argv[2],"wb");   //OPEN IN BINARY WRITE MODE
    if (outf == NULL)       //CHECK FOR WRITE FILE 
    {   fprintf(stderr, "FILE OPENING ERROR\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int j=0;j<max_ele;j++)
    {   //HAVE TO WRITE EACH ELEMENT INDIVIDUALLY TO MATCH SAMPLE OUTPUT FILE.
        fwrite(&arr[j].sheet,sizeof(arr[j].sheet),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].condition,sizeof(arr[j].condition),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].ant,sizeof(arr[j].ant),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].crack,sizeof(arr[j].crack),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].throne,sizeof(arr[j].throne),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].trade,sizeof(arr[j].trade),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].cry,sizeof(arr[j].cry),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].pigs,sizeof(arr[j].pigs),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].quartz,sizeof(arr[j].quartz),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].wash,sizeof(arr[j].wash),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].industry,sizeof(arr[j].industry),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].pin,sizeof(arr[j].pin),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].doctor,sizeof(arr[j].doctor),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].plantation,sizeof(arr[j].plantation),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].scarf,sizeof(arr[j].scarf),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].lake,sizeof(arr[j].lake),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].jump,sizeof(arr[j].jump),1,outf);
        }
    
    free(arr);
    //FILE WRITE CONFIRMATION
        printf("\n%s written successfully.",argv[2]);
        //CLOSE FILE POINTER
        fclose(outf);

return 0;

}
```

The code not using pointers

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct strdef {                          /*strdef = structure definition*/

        float sheet;                     /*32-bit floating point*/
        uint32_t condition;              /*32-bit boolean*/
        uint64_t ant;                    /*64-bit unsigned integer*//*hexadecimal converted to  decimal number 457*/
        uint32_t crack;                  /*32-bit integer*//*decimal value 47 converted to octal notation*/
        uint32_t throne;                 /*32-bit integer*/
        bool trade;                      /*8-bit boolean*/
        bool cry;                        /*8-bit boolean*/
        uint32_t pigs;                   /*32-bit boolean*/
        uint32_t quartz;                 /*32-bit boolean*/
        char wash[9];                    /*at most 9-bit string*/
        char industry;                   /*8-bit character*/
        double pin;                      /*64-bit floating point*/
        float doctor;                    /*32-bit floating point*/
        int16_t plantation;              /*16-bit integer*//*Convert from decimal to hexadecimal*/
        uint8_t scarf;                   /*8-bit integer*//*decimal value 125 converted to octal notation*/
        int8_t lake;                     /*8-bit integer*/
        bool jump;                       /*8-bit boolean*/

};


int max_ele=1;
int MAX=37;

//THE COMPARATOR FUNCTION.
int comp(const void * aa, const void * bb)
{
    struct strdef a = *(struct strdef*)aa;
    struct strdef b = *(struct strdef*)bb;
    if (a.sheet==b.sheet)
    {   if (a.ant==b.ant)   
        {   if (a.pigs==b.pigs) 
            {   if (a.industry==b.industry) 
        {   if (a.pin==b.pin)   
            {   if (a.quartz==b.quartz) 
            {   if (a.condition==b.condition)   
                {   if (a.jump==b.jump) 
                {   if (a.doctor==b.doctor) 
                    {   if (a.throne==b.throne) 
                    {   if (a.crack==b.crack)
                        {   if (a.plantation==b.plantation) 
                        {   if (strcmp(a.wash,b.wash)==0)   
                            {   if (a.cry==b.cry)   
                            {   if (a.lake==b.lake) 
                                {   if (a.scarf==b.scarf)       
                                {   if (a.trade==b.trade)   
                                        return 0;
                                    else if (a.trade < b.trade) //trade -- desc
                                    return 1;
                                    else
                                    return -1;
                                }
                                else if (a.scarf < b.scarf) //scarf -- desc
                                    return 1;
                                else
                                    return -1;
                                }
                                else if (a.lake < b.lake)       //lake -- desc
                                return 1;
                                else
                                return -1;
                            }
                            else if (a.cry < b.cry)         //cry -- asc
                                return -1;
                            else
                                return 1;
                            }
                            else if (strcmp(a.wash,b.wash)>0)       //wash -- asc
                            return 1;
                            else
                            return -1;
                        }
                        else if (a.plantation < b.plantation)       //plantation -- asc
                            return -1;
                        else
                            return 1;
                        }
                        else if (a.crack < b.crack)             //crack -- asc
                        return -1;
                        else
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else if (a.throne < b.throne)               //throne -- desc
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return -1;
                    }
                    else if (a.doctor < b.doctor)               //doctor -- asc
                    return -1;
                    else
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (a.jump < b.jump)                   //jump -- asc
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 1;
                }                   
                else if (a.condition < b.condition)                 //condition -- desc
                return 1;
                else
                return -1;
            }
            else if (a.quartz < b.quartz)                       //quartz -- asc
                return -1;
            else
                return 1;
            }
            else if (a.pin < b.pin)                         //pin -- desc
            return 1;
            else
            return -1;
        }
        else if (a.industry < b.industry)                       //industry -- desc
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
            }
            else if (a.pigs < b.pigs)                               //pigs -- asc
            return -1;
            else
            return 1;
        }
        else if (a.ant < b.ant)                                 //ant -- desc
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    else if (a.sheet < b.sheet)                                 //sheet -- desc
            return 1;
    else
            return -1;
} // comp

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Declaring File pointer
    FILE *f;
    //opening File in read-binary mode
    f=fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    //Defining Struct strdef variable
    struct strdef rec1;
    //Checking if File is found and opened.
    if (f == NULL)
    {   fprintf(stderr, "%s File Not found\n",argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!f)
    {   printf( "Usage: %s inputfile %s outputfile\n", argv[1],argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //DYNAMICALL ALLOCATE MEMORY BLOCK.
    struct strdef * arr = (struct strdef*)malloc(sizeof(struct strdef)*MAX);
    struct strdef * arr_nw=NULL;
    int i=0;

    //Read file until End Of File is reached.
    while(1) 
    {   fread(&rec1.sheet,sizeof(rec1.sheet),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.condition,sizeof(rec1.condition),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.ant,sizeof(rec1.ant),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.crack,sizeof(rec1.crack),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.throne,sizeof(rec1.throne),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.trade,sizeof(rec1.trade),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.cry,sizeof(rec1.cry),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.pigs,sizeof(rec1.pigs),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.quartz,sizeof(rec1.quartz),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.wash,sizeof(rec1.wash),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.industry,sizeof(rec1.industry),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.pin,sizeof(rec1.pin),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.doctor,sizeof(rec1.doctor),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.plantation,sizeof(rec1.plantation),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.scarf,sizeof(rec1.scarf),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.lake,sizeof(rec1.lake),1,f);
            fread(&rec1.jump,sizeof(rec1.jump),1,f);
        
        //When end of file reached, Break loop.
        if(feof(f)!=0)
                break;      
            
            //CHECK WHEN ALLOCATED MEMORY BLOCK IS OVER
            if(i>=MAX)
        {   arr_nw = realloc(arr,sizeof(struct strdef)*(i+1));
            
            if(arr_nw==NULL)
            {   printf("reallocation not done");
                break;
            }
            else
            {   arr_nw[i]=rec1;
                arr=arr_nw;
            }
        }
            
        else
                *(arr+i)=rec1;
            i++;    

    }
    //CLOSE FILE POINTER
    fclose(f);

    max_ele=i;      //SET NUMBER OF RECORDS.
//QSORT FUNCTION CALL
    qsort(arr,max_ele,sizeof(struct strdef),comp);
    
//FILE POINTER FOR WRITE OPERATION
    FILE * outf;
        outf=fopen(argv[2],"wb");   //OPEN IN BINARY WRITE MODE
    if (outf == NULL)       //CHECK FOR WRITE FILE 
    {   fprintf(stderr, "FILE OPENING ERROR\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int j=0;j<max_ele;j++)
    {   //HAVE TO WRITE EACH ELEMENT INDIVIDUALLY TO MATCH SAMPLE OUTPUT FILE.
        fwrite(&arr[j].sheet,sizeof(arr[j].sheet),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].condition,sizeof(arr[j].condition),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].ant,sizeof(arr[j].ant),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].crack,sizeof(arr[j].crack),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].throne,sizeof(arr[j].throne),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].trade,sizeof(arr[j].trade),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].cry,sizeof(arr[j].cry),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].pigs,sizeof(arr[j].pigs),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].quartz,sizeof(arr[j].quartz),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].wash,sizeof(arr[j].wash),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].industry,sizeof(arr[j].industry),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].pin,sizeof(arr[j].pin),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].doctor,sizeof(arr[j].doctor),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].plantation,sizeof(arr[j].plantation),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].scarf,sizeof(arr[j].scarf),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].lake,sizeof(arr[j].lake),1,outf);
            fwrite(&arr[j].jump,sizeof(arr[j].jump),1,outf);
        }
    
    free(arr);
    //FILE WRITE CONFIRMATION
        printf("\n%s written successfully.",argv[2]);
        //CLOSE FILE POINTER
        fclose(outf);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: @oseph Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I can practically guarantee you that comparator function has bugs. It's a total mess, and really error prone. I'd suggest you invert the `if` statements' predicates, and use an early-return pattern. See https://refactoring.guru/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses

Comment: That `comp` function is a work of art. I can only imagine how it might look properly formatted.

Comment: Start by deleting your entire compare function and use a struct that has 1 or 2 fields. Then get that working. Then add more fields to your struct and modify your compare function, following Alexander's recommendation of doing early returns rather than nesting everything together into a big mess.

Comment: Code is not sorting pointers, but by the content of the structure.  Joseph, is your true goal to sort pointers, or sort by what they point to?

Comment: If you remove every `&` in the comp function you're having trouble with and turn on compiler warnings so you can see and fix the various format string issues you'd be in better shape.

Comment: `char wash[9];   /*at most 9-bit string*/` is confusing - 9 _bits_?  Post an example of the longest data stored in `wash[]`.

Comment: You say you want to sort an array of pointers, but you don't *have* an array of pointers.  You have a pointer to the first element of a dynamic array of structures. You can use that pointer in many of the same ways you would use an ordinary array.

Comment: Thank you. I will give everything a go.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to understand what is the criteria of sorting.

Nevertheless you are trying to sort an array of objects of a structure type

```
qsort(arr,max_ele,sizeof(struct strdef),comp);
```

where the array pointed to by the pointer `arr` is allocated like

```
struct strdef * arr = (struct strdef*)malloc(sizeof(struct strdef)*MAX);
```

So the function `comp` deals with pointers to objects of the type `struct strdef`.

Thus the beginning of the comparison function should look like

```
//THE COMPARATOR FUNCTION.
int comp(const void * aa, const void * bb)
{   
    const struct strdef *left = aa;
    const struct strdef *right = bb;

    if ( left->sheet == right->sheet )
    // and so on...
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct strdef 
{
    float sheet; 
    char wash[9];
};

const size_t MAX = 3;

int comp( const void * aa, const void * bb )
{   
    const struct strdef *left = aa;
    const struct strdef *right = bb;
    
    if ( left->sheet < right->sheet )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( right->sheet < left->sheet ) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return strcmp( left->wash, right->wash );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct strdef * arr = malloc( sizeof( struct strdef ) * MAX );
    
    arr[0].sheet = 2.0;
    strcpy( arr[0].wash, "A" );
    
    arr[1].sheet = 1.0;
    strcpy( arr[1].wash, "C" );
    
    arr[2].sheet = 1.0;
    strcpy( arr[2].wash, "B" );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%zu: %.1f, %s\n", i, arr[i].sheet, arr[i].wash );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    qsort( arr, MAX, sizeof( struct strdef ), comp );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%zu: %.1f, %s\n", i, arr[i].sheet, arr[i].wash );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    free( arr );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0: 2.0, A
1: 1.0, C
2: 1.0, B

0: 1.0, B
1: 1.0, C
2: 2.0, A
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a lot of confusion about how pointers work.

These two lines at the beginning of your function are completely wrong:

```
struct strdef *left = *(struct strdef**)aa;
struct strdef *right = *(struct strdef**)bb;
```

You are casting a simple pointer to "pointer to pointer" and then trying to dereference that and putting it in a pointer.

This results in shoving the first 8 (or 4 if you are on a 32 bit system) bytes of `struct strdef` in to `left` and `right` to be treated as memory address (aka "pointer").

But in reality, this would be `sheet` member, and probably the `condition` member as well.

Then in this line:

```
printf("sheet checked %f  %f  \n\n",&(left->sheet),&(right->sheet));
```

You are trying to dereference those bad addresses which should cause your program to segfault.

And you are also trying to get the addresses of the struct members, even though you want to print their values.

Finally, when you do things like this:

```
if (&left->sheet==&right->sheet)
```

You are once again accessing some random bytes.
This part will be too difficult to explain at your current level, it has to do with how C works with structures, but lets just say it is completely wrong.

A pointer is a variable that contains a memory address.
You use * when you want to access the value that is stored in memory at that address.
You only use & when you have a variable and you want to know **its** address.

So, getting rid of all the misuses of & and * your code should look something like this:

```
//THE COMPARATOR FUNCTION.
int comp(const void * aa, const void * bb)
{
    struct strdef *a = (struct strdef*)aa;
    struct strdef *b = (struct strdef*)bb;

    if (a->sheet == b->sheet) {
        if (a->ant == b->ant) {
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind I did not check your conditions, so the function may still not compare correctly, but at least it will check the actual values you want to compare.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to various problems:

**Avoid the indent [morass](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/morass)**

In comparing, try something like, which also avoids subtraction overflow.

```
if (left->sheet != right->sheet) {
  return (left->sheet > right->sheet) - (left->sheet < right->sheet);
}
if (left->ant != right->ant) {
  return (left->ant > right->ant) - (left->ant < right->ant);
}
if (left->pigs != right->pigs) {
  return (left->pigs > right->pigs) - (left->pigs < right->pigs);
}
...
```